# new pandas column from a parsed json dictionary column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the following structure

```
col1 col2 col3
1     2   {"a":{"b":2, "c":3}}
```

col3 contains parsed json as a dictionary, im trying to make a new column for c but not for the rest.
applying pandas i managed to do

```
df["col3"].transform(lambda x: x.get("a").get("c") )
```

and it worked for c but now when writing the same code for b i get back 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.

(also this is my first question here so very sorry if anything is unclear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
In [390]: df['c'] = df['col3'].str.get('a').str.get('c')

In [391]: df
Out[391]: 
   col1  col2                     col3  c
0     1     2  {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}  3
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option might be to use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df['c'] = pd.json_normalize(df['col3'])['a.c']
```

output:

```
   col1  col2                     col3  c
0     1     2  {'a': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}  3
```